# Displaying artist data from network response via Spotify API

Tags: reactjs, response, spotify

Here is my Code.

```
    spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: { 
              name: response.item.name,
              artist: response.item.artists.name,
              albumArt: response.item.album.images[0].url
            }
        });
      })
```

my response object for 'artist:' is not displaying the artists' name. How can I change

```
artist: response.item.artists.name,
```

to get "Key Glock" to display?
Here is the network response data.

```
"item" : {
    "album" : {
      "album_type" : "album",
      "artists" : [ {
        "external_urls" : {
          "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/0RESbWvOMyua0yuyVrztJ5"
        },
        "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/0RESbWvOMyua0yuyVrztJ5",
        "id" : "0RESbWvOMyua0yuyVrztJ5",
        "name" : "Key Glock",
        "type" : "artist",
        "uri" : "spotify:artist:0RESbWvOMyua0yuyVrztJ5"
      } ],
      "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AE", "AG", "AL", "AM", "AO", "AR", "AT", "AU", "AZ", "BA", "BB", "BD", "BE", "BF", "BG", "BH", "BI", "BJ", "BN", "BO", "BR", "BS", "BT", "BW", "BY", "BZ", "CA", "CD", "CG", "CH", "CI", "CL", "CM", "CO", "CR", "CV", "CW", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DJ", "DK", "DM", "DO", "DZ", "EC", "EE", "EG", "ES", "FI", "FJ", "FM", "FR", "GA", "GB", "GD", "GE", "GH", "GM", "GN", "GQ", "GR", "GT", "GW", "GY", "HK", "HN", "HR", "HT", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IL", "IN", "IQ", "IS", "IT", "JM", "JO", "JP", "KE", "KG", "KH", "KI", "KM", "KN", "KR", "KW", "KZ", "LA", "LB", "LC", "LI", "LK", "LR", "LS", "LT", "LU", "LV", "LY", "MA", "MC", "MD", "ME", "MG", "MH", "MK", "ML", "MN", "MO", "MR", "MT", "MU", "MV", "MW", "MX", "MY", "MZ", "NA", "NE", "NG", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NP", "NR", "NZ", "OM", "PA", "PE", "PG", "PH", "PK", "PL", "PS", "PT", "PW", "PY", "QA", "RO", "RS", "RU", "RW", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SE", "SG", "SI", "SK", "SL", "SM", "SN", "SR", "ST", "SV", "SZ", "TD", "TG", "TH", "TJ", "TL", "TN", "TO", "TR", "TT", "TV", "TW", "TZ", "UA", "UG", "US", "UY", "UZ", "VC", "VE", "VN", "VU", "WS", "XK", "ZA", "ZM", "ZW" ],
      "external_urls" : {
        "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/7snqOEQEtKqxJw3NTGml6i"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`artists` is an array, presumably the spotify API would return multiple artists if you had two or more artists on a track, which we would normally write "Jim feat. John".

To get the first artist's name: `response.item.album.artists[0].name`

To get all the artists' names: `response.item.album.artists.map(curr => curr.name)`

Comment: Thanks Ben! This answer was the solution :)